# 2D Array not properly accessing globalvar (GameMaker)

Tags: game-maker, gml, game-maker-language, game-maker-studio-2

I have a shop that I am attempting to set up that by all accounts inside of the Debugger is triggering, but doing absolutely nothing.

This is the set up that I have:

`o_Shop` - Player interacts to create a layer inside of room0

`o_Shop_setup` - Creation of Array, Create Event:

```
global.inventory[1, 1] = "Mines";               //Item Name
global.inventory[1, 2] = sp_Blue_mine_UI;       //Item Sprite
global.inventory[1, 3] = 50;                    //Cost
global.inventory[1, 4] = MINE_NUMBER;           //Current Inventory
global.inventory[1, 5] = MINE_NUMBER_MAXIMUM;   //Maximum amount

//HE Ammo
global.inventory[2, 1] = "HE Ammo";             //Item Name
global.inventory[2, 2] = sp_ammoHE;             //Item Sprite
global.inventory[2, 3] = 5;                     //Cost
global.inventory[2, 4] = AMMO_AMOUNT;           //Current Inventory
global.inventory[2, 5] = AMMO_AMOUNT_MAXIMUM;   //Maximum amount
```

Then, I use the follow objects that access that array:

o_item_parent - Parent of o_shop_Mines/o_shop_AmmoHE
- Inside of o_item_parent Draw Event:

```
draw_set_font(fnt_small);
draw_set_halign(fa_center);
draw_set_valign(fa_middle);
draw_set_color(c_white);
draw_text(x, y - 100, global.inventory[myid, 1]);
draw_sprite(global.inventory[myid, 2], 0, x, y - 30);
draw_set_color(c_yellow);
draw_text(x, y + 32, string(global.inventory[myid, 3]) + " Coins");
draw_set_color(c_white);
draw_text(x, y + 64, string(global.inventory[myid, 4]) + " / " + string(global.inventory[myid, 5]));
```

o_shop_Mines - Inherits the Draw Event with no changes.

### o_shop_Mines Create Event:

```
myid = 1;
```

o_shop_AmmoHE - Inherits the Draw Event with no changes.
o_shop_AmmoHe Create Event:

```
 myid = 2;
```

o_buy_parent - Parent of o_buy_Mines/o_buy_ammoHE
o_buy_parent - Create Event:

```
image_speed = 0;
image_index = 0;
```

### `o_buy_parent` Step Event:

```
if (COINS >= global.inventory[myid, 3])
{
    image_index = 0;    
}
else
{
    image_index = 1;    
}

if (global.inventory[myid, 4] == global.inventory[myid, 5])
{
    image_index = 1;    
}
```

### `o_buy_parent` Left Pressed Event:

```
if (global.inventory[myid, 4] == global.inventory[myid, 5])
{
    audio_play_sound(snd_gunReload, 1, false);
}
else if (COINS < global.inventory[myid, 3])
{
    audio_play_sound(snd_game_over, 1, false);  
}
else
{
    //audio play sound snd_purchase_complete
    COINS -= global.inventory[myid, 3];
    global.inventory[myid,4]++;
}
```

`o_buy_Mines` - Inherits Step Event/Left Pressed Event from o_buy_parent

### Inside of `o_buy_Mines` Create Event:

```
myid = 1;
event_inherited();
```

`o_buy_ammoHE` - Inherits Step Event/Left Pressed Event from o_buy_parent

### Inside of `o_buy_ammoHE` Create Event:

```
myid = 2;
event_inherited();
```

### Inside of `o_buy_ammoHE` Create Event:

```
myid = 2;
event_inherited();
```

### Inside of `o_buy_ammoHE` Left Pressed Event:

```
if (global.inventory[myid, 4] == global.inventory[myid, 5])
{
    audio_play_sound(snd_gunReload, 1, false);
}
else if (COINS < global.inventory[myid, 3])
{
    audio_play_sound(snd_game_over, 1, false);  
}
else
{
    //audio play sound snd_purchase_complete
    COINS -= global.inventory[myid, 3];
    global.inventory[myid,4]++; //breakpoint triggers fine, does nothing.
    //Have also tried the below line, doesn't work, but commented out    currently:
    //AMMO_AMOUNT += 5;
}
```

All variables in ALL CAPS are global variables created using globalvar method inside of `o_init`
o_init`is inside of room ->`rm_LoadingScreen`

`rm_LoadingScreen` does nothing but hold this object which is not persistent, this object contains a
switch statement that can change `STATE = GameState` (enum)

```
`STATE = GameState.menu` is called by default which calls
scr_menuLoader();
break;
```

Everything is working except the store. It *did* work yesterday but I'm having trouble tracking down what I broke. As currently, the code is incrementing a number that is drawn to the screen by

```
draw_text(x, y + 64, string(global.inventory[myid, 4]) + " / " + string    (global.inventory[myid, 5]));
```

but the globalvar AMMO_AMOUNT is not changing. The debugger shows it as never changing.

Can anyone provide some feedback or a second set of eyes? I've been staring at this for hours and I just can't see a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The use you are doing for AMMO_AMOUNT and other names with caps is the equivalent for a constant, used as an initial value. Anyway It seems the value in global.inventory[myid,4] has already increased.
So if you want to change the value of AMMO_AMOUNT you should do it explicitly, just like you have in the commented line: //AMMO_AMOUNT += 5;
I hope you haven't commented it by mistake XD

In the end, your code should be like:
Inside of **o_buy_ammoHE** Left Pressed Event, the last **else** block:

```
else
{
    //audio play sound snd_purchase_complete
    COINS -= global.inventory[myid, 3];
    global.inventory[myid,4]++; 
    AMMO_AMOUNT = global.inventory[myid,4];
}
```

if it doesn't help, I would think that everything is working as expected and you just have to use global.inventory[myid, 4]) where needed.